# What method do I use to reload my listview after onBackPressed() is called in my Third Activity

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, onbackpressed

Here I have 3 Activities:
My first activity (Activity A) has an edit text, button, and listview.
This activity adds whatever is typed in the edit text into the listview.

My second activity (Activity B) is opened after the user clicks in the listview. 
This activity acts as a logger for my app.

My third activity (Activity C) is a TabHost. When I move 'backwards' I  return to Activity A HOWEVER my Listview from Activity A is EMPTY.

Why?
How can I fix this issue?

Activity A --> Activity B --> Activity C.

Here is my code Activity A:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.sdsmdg.tastytoast.TastyToast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static int CODE = 1; //declare as FIELD

    DatabaseHelper db;
    ListView lv;
    EditText nameTxt;
    ImageView savebtn;
    ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);


        //reference to the database to make sure the vacation titles are stored
        db = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        //edit text to enter a vacation
        //--XML is vacationTitleTB--//
        nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.vacationTitleTB);

        //save button to save into the listview later on
        //--XML is createVacationTitleButton--//
        savebtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.planeimage);


        //list view to store all of the vacation titles in, as long as the emulator stays running
        //--XML is vacationTitlesListView--//
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.vacationTitlesListView);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);


        savebtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //inserting the vacation title into the database
                System.out.println(nameTxt.getText().toString());

                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                //getting the vacation title name
                String getText = nameTxt.getText().toString();

                //checking to make sure that something was typed into the edit text,but is not the same edit text as already entered
                if (arr.contains(getText))
                {
                    TastyToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Same vacation?? Click on the one you already made. Just add onto it.", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.DEFAULT);
                }
                //checking to make sure that the edit text is not left blank
                else if (getText == null || getText.trim().equals(""))
                {
                    TastyToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Excuse me, you need a Vacation Title for your vacation.", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.DEFAULT);
                }
                //otherwise add this to the array list
                else
                {
                    db.insertData2(new VacationTitleLog(nameTxt.getText().toString()));
                    arr.add(getText);
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


                    //go to the next page
                }
            }
        });


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Main.class);
                //pass the vacation title to the next page
                intent1.putExtra("vacationtitlenamed", nameTxt.getText().toString());
                //launch the intent to Main
                startActivity(intent1);


            }
        });

    }


}
```

Here is my code Activity B:

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceSelectionListener;
import com.sdsmdg.tastytoast.TastyToast;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;


public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    DatabaseHelper myDB;
    Button btnDatePicker, btnDatePicker2, btnViewAll, btnDelete, forward, backward;
    TextView title, from, to;
    EditText txtDate, txtDate2;//,  id;
    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay;
    private int mYear2, mMonth2, mDay2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        myDB = new DatabaseHelper(this);


        btnDatePicker = (Button) findViewById(R.id.in_button);
        btnDatePicker2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.out_button);


        btnDatePicker.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnDatePicker2.setOnClickListener(this);

        title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tit);

        forward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forwardBtn);
        backward = (Button) findViewById(R.id.backBtn);


        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        Bundle bd = intent1.getExtras();
        if (bd != null) {
            String vt = bd.getString("vacationtitlenamed");

            title.setText("Vacation Title " + "\n" + vt);

        }


        from = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        to = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        txtDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
        txtDate2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtDate2);

        btnViewAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.viewAllButton);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);


        PlaceAutocompleteFragment places = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);
        places.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {

                from.setText(place.getName().toString());
                System.out.println(place.getName());
                //from.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                SingletonFromTo.getInstance().setFrom(from.getText().toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }


        });

        PlaceAutocompleteFragment places2 = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment2);
        places2.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place2) {

                to.setText(place2.getName().toString());
                System.out.println(place2.getName());
                //to.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                SingletonFromTo.getInstance().setTo(to.getText().toString());


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Status status2) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), status2.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

        previous();
        addData();
        viewAll();
        deleteAll();

    }

    private void previous() {
        backward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Main.super.onBackPressed();

            }
        });

    }


    public void deleteAll()
    {
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                myDB.deleteAllData();
            }
        });

    }


    public void addData()
    {
        forward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (from.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    TastyToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to enter in a from location", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.DEFAULT);

                }
                else if (to.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    TastyToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to enter in a to location",TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.DEFAULT);

                }
                else if (txtDate.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    TastyToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to enter in a start date",TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.DEFAULT);


                }
                else if (txtDate2.getText().length() == 0)
                {
                    TastyToast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You need to enter in a end date", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG,TastyToast.DEFAULT);
                }
                else
                {

                    System.out.println(txtDate.getText().toString());

                    System.out.println(txtDate2.getText().toString());

                    myDB.insertData(new VacationInfoLog(from.getText().toString(), to.getText().toString(), txtDate.getText().toString(), txtDate2.getText().toString()));



                   // myDB.queryToVacationTitle();

                    //store the data here
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(Main.this, TabbedActivity.class);
                    intent2.putExtra("title", title.getText().toString());


                    SingletonFromTo.getInstance().setFrom(from.getText().toString());
                    SingletonFromTo.getInstance().setTo(to.getText().toString());

                    //intent2.putExtra("f", from.getText().toString());
                    //intent2.putExtra("t", to.getText().toString());
                    SingletonFromTo.getInstance().setStart(txtDate.getText().toString());
                    SingletonFromTo.getInstance().setEnd(txtDate2.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent2);






                }

            }
        });

    }

    public void viewAll() {
        btnViewAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                List<VacationInfoLog> res = myDB.getAllData();


                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                for (VacationInfoLog info : res) {
                    buffer.append("ID : " + info.getID() + "\n");
                    buffer.append("From : " + info.getFrom() + "\n");
                    buffer.append("To : " + info.getTo() + "\n");
                    buffer.append("Start : " + info.getStart() + "\n");
                    buffer.append("End : " + info.getEnd() + "\n\n");
                }


                showMessage("Vacations", buffer.toString());
            }
        });

    }


    public void showMessage(String title, String message)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {

        if (v == btnDatePicker)
        {
            // Get Current Date
            java.util.Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

                            txtDate.setText((monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year);

                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();

        }

        if (v == btnDatePicker2)
        {
            // Get Current Date
            java.util.Calendar c2 = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear2 = c2.get(java.util.Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth2 = c2.get(java.util.Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay2 = c2.get(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtDate2.setText((monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth + "-" + year);


                }
            }, mYear2, mMonth2, mDay2);

            datePickerDialog.show();

        }

        /*String i = txtDate.getText().toString();
        String k = txtDate2.getText().toString();



        if(i.compareTo(k) < 0)
        {

            System.out.println("HERE");
        }*/



    }

}
```

Here is my code Activity C: *LOOK CLOSELY AT MY ONBACKPRESSED()*

```
import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class TabbedActivity extends TabActivity {
    TextView tv_from, tv_to, tv_start, tv_end;
    TabHost tabHost;
    final Context context = this;
    TextView t;
    TextView d;
    ListView lst;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabs);


        viewOneItem();


        //Assign id to Tabhost.
        tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);



        //Creating tab menu.
        final TabHost.TabSpec TabMenu1 = tabHost.newTabSpec("First tab");
        final TabHost.TabSpec TabMenu2 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Second Tab");
        final TabHost.TabSpec TabMenu3 = tabHost.newTabSpec("Third Tab");


        //Setting up tab 1 name.
        TabMenu1.setIndicator("Trip");
        //Set tab 1 activity to tab 1 menu.
        //TabMenu1.setContent(new Intent(this,TabActivity_1.class));
        TabMenu1.setContent(R.id.tab1);


        //Setting up tab 2 name.
        TabMenu2.setIndicator("Map");
        //Set tab 3 activity to tab 1 menu.
        //TabMenu2.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity_2.class));
        //TabMenu2.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        //TabMenu2.setContent(new Intent(this,DialogInMap.class));
        TabMenu2.setContent(new Intent(this,TabActivity_2.class));


        //Setting up tab 2 name.
        TabMenu3.setIndicator("Record");
        //Set tab 3 activity to tab 3 menu.
        //TabMenu3.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        TabMenu3.setContent(new Intent(this, TabActivity_3.class));



        //Adding tab1, tab2, tab3 to tabhost view.

        tabHost.addTab(TabMenu1);
        tabHost.addTab(TabMenu2);
        tabHost.addTab(TabMenu3);




    }

    public void viewOneItem() {
        tv_from = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_from);
        tv_to = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_to);
        tv_start = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_start);
        tv_end = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_end);

       // tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Intent intent2 = getIntent();
        Bundle bd = intent2.getExtras();

        if(bd != null)
        {
            String fr = bd.getString("f");
            String toooo= bd.getString("t");
            String st = bd.getString("s");
            String en = bd.getString("e");


            tv_from.setText("From " + SingletonFromTo.getInstance().getFrom());
            tv_to.setText("To " + SingletonFromTo.getInstance().getTo());
            //tv_from.setText("From " + fr);
            //tv_to.setText("To " + toooo);
            tv_start.setText("Start " +SingletonFromTo.getInstance().getStart());
            //tv_start.setText("Start " + st);

           // tv_end.setText("End " + en);

            tv_end.setText("End " + SingletonFromTo.getInstance().getEnd());

//            String f = bd.getString("f");
  //          tv.setText(f);
        }



    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        Intent inte = new Intent(TabbedActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(inte);
    }



    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.tab1:
                return true;
            case R.id.tab2:
                return true;
            case R.id.tab3:
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your activity is empty because you don't go back to Activity A, you start another instance of it.

When user gets logged in and Activity B finishes and Activity C starts. Activity A is still running. To go back to it from Activity C don't override `onBackPressed` but keep the default behavior which closes the activity on back press. It should normally go back to Activity A.

Comment: By removing @Override for onBackPressed() still emptied my listview from Activity A.

Comment: Remove the whole `onBackPress` method from your Activity C

Comment: If I remove the whole method and go back...it would go to Activity B

Comment: In Activity B after you start Activity C, call `finish()`. It should close Activity B so that Activity C will go back to Activity A when back is pressed.

Comment: OK..did that and this worked! It went back to Activity A but when I clicked on the Listview item in Activity A it went to Activity B (look closely at my listview item click listener in Activity A)...how do I go to Activity C the SECOND time around?

Comment: Do you have a way to detect if user is connected? If you do then start Activity  C if user is logged in, Activity B otherwise.

Comment: So basically..the User enters in a Vacation title in Activity A...next the user clicks on that Vacation title that is in the listview to go to Activity B.Now if the 'Next' button is clicked in Activity B then YES the user IS logged and the info IS transferred to my Activity C properly. However when I go back... it returns to Activity A *good* ... but when I click on the item in Activity A...it returns to Activity B. I am not sure why??

Comment: Do you have any idea?

Comment: Start Activity C instead of Activity B on list item click if user is already connected.

Comment: How can you know if user is connected? Do you have something like `DatabaseHelper.isUserConnected()`?